# Bluetooth On/Off toggle not showing in Windows 8.1 PC Settings

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, usb, bluetooth

I have recently purchased a cheap Bluetooth USB dongle from a local shop and plugged it in into my freshly installed Windows 8.1 Pro laptop, as it did not come with a Bluetooth adapter installed. All went good, I have a Bluetooth icon in my taskbar, but unfortunately a toggle to switch Bluetooth on/off in PC Settings - PC and devices - Bluetooth was not added. I would really like to have the option to switch the Bluetooth device on/off from there. Also, airplane mode does not disable Bluetooth, just Wi-Fi. Please tell me the steps needed to have this toggle available in PC settings...

P.S. My Bluetooth USB dongle is listed in Device manager as a Generic Bluetooth Radio made by Cambridge Sillicon Radio.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, bluetooth settings not properly appearing under "PC and devices" is a driver issue.  I'd recommend going to the Bluetooth USB dongle manufacturer's website and downloading/installing the latest drives for Windows 8.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that it does not have a specific driver. The manufacturer is some little Chinese company which provides no driver, so Windows installs a generic driver which works very well except the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found it by searching on wireless, selecting turn wireless devices on and off and the option for Bluetooth was there.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. There should be when you right mouseclick on the bluetooth icon in de task bar the option "bluetooth radio switch off, or on when switchjed off".  I managed to get that by installing the "CSR Harmony Wirelesss Softwarestack" from the CDRom that came with the sitecom bluetooth adapter. It should be able to download that program somewehere on the internet.